# Add NDVI Date to stacked image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, stack

I have created an Image collection in GEE, and I have computed NDVI index and mapped in each Imagen from Collection. Later, I create another collection with NDVI as a band, an finally Statacked in a Imagen each NDVI band.
BUT the question is: how add the NDVI´s DATES in each band of the Stacked Image?

```
function addNDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('ndvi')
  return image.addBands([ndvi])
}
var collection = ee.ImageCollection ("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterMetadata ("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", "Less_Than", 30)
  .map(addNDVI)

print(collection)

var Coleccion_ndvi =  collection.select(["ndvi"])
print(Coleccion_ndvi)

var stackCollection = function(collection) {
  var first = ee.Image(collection.first()).select([]);
  var appendBands = function(image, previous) {
    return ee.Image(previous).addBands(image);
  };
  return ee.Image(collection.iterate(appendBands, first));
};
var stacked = stackCollection(Coleccion_ndvi);
print('stacked image', stacked);
```

Comment: You'd probably better use `imageCollection.toBands()`. Where you want to add the NDVI date? As pixel value? As image band name? As property to each image?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I am trying to add As image band name.

Comment: Thank with Collection_ndvi.toBands() works really efficiently.

Comment: Thanks Kuik, with imageCollection.toBands()   it solved . But, I´m trying to convert the final image with 148 ndvi's bands  (per date) in a CSV file using every "ndvi_date (band)" like a column.  Whit CSV file I can use R Studio and R Libraries to Analize  band per band.